# Could any one explain me about the usage of HttpHandlers and Generic Handlers in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a bit confusion about the Http Handlers,Generic Handlers  and the usage of those two.Could any explain me ?

Comment: Here is all about Handlers (MSDN)- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx

Comment: Could you be more specific about your confusion? What don't you get?

Answer (score 1):

The Generic Handler is a ashx file. You can basically make it return anything (image, json, html, etc.).

The Http Handler would be a class library that you can distribute and can be deployed by changing the web.config. The purpose would be the same as the Generic Handler.

I guess they accomplish the same thing. It's mostly a matter of how you intend to implement (a file in your web.project vs. class library) and distribute it.